# Setting Qt Creator to use the latest version of g++ and gdb on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, g++, qt-creator

I wish to use the C++11 features in a Qt programs compiled by GNU C++ compiler (MinGW) on Windows. By this reason I can not use a version of compiler provided in Qt SDK.

I decided to use the latest versions of Qt, Qt Creator and MinGW. By this reason, I download and install these software separately. It is easy to set up the Qt Creator to use the version of Qt installed in `C:\Qt` folder and GNU C++ compiler from MinGW installed to `C:\MinGW` folder, but a debugging does not work then. More specific, I receive error:

`"During startup program exited with code 0x0"`

How to fix it? What is a correct setting for the debugger in the toolchain options?

Comment: Yes. Python 2.7.2 is installed in C:\Python27 folder, but how to set up the Qt Creator to find it?

Comment: The question text is changed. Please, read it again.

Comment: You changed the question entirely.  So Python is not your problem.  No idea what the issue is.  Programs exiting with code 0 usually mean everything is ok.

Comment: Have you tried making your program start with `cin.get()`, in case you are encountering this bug?  https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTCREATORBUG-4997

Comment: Thank You. Using cin.get() as the first command in program solves the problem. I am surprising because I have this problem in Qt Creator 2.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

QtCreator requires a patched version of gdb to works. It's a workaround

1. To make the --tty option work under MinGW and
2. To prevent gdb from freezing when attaching to a suspended process.

You have 2 alternatives (assuming that you are entirely satisfied with the prior installation of the framework and the compiler):

1. Download the patched gdb binary from Qt's repository or
2. Download the patches from Qt's site, apply them and build gdb

Install the debugger to the appropriate directory and finally resume the configuration of the debugger.

Comment: Presumably, you work under Windows judging from the path you provide in your question.